# Why Arrays.sort(arr) is returning 0 values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
class stoner {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = ob.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[501];
        while(t-- > 0)
        {
            int s = ob.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0;i<s;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = ob.nextInt();
                Arrays.sort(arr);
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<s;i++)
                System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**INPUT:**
1(the test case)
5(size of array)
5 2 3 1 4 (the array elements)

**OUTPUT:**
0 0 0 0 0

Why even after using this sort function we are getting 0's as answer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only fill 5 elements of the array (you entered 5 as the "size of array"), most of the 501 elements of your array will contain 0s by default, and after sorting the array, the 0s come before the positive values you entered.

In addition, you should sort the array just one time, after assigning all the inputs into the array.

```
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = ob.nextInt();
    while(t-- > 0)
    {
        int s = ob.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[s]; // give the array the correct length
        for(int i = 0; i<s; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = ob.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr); // sort after reading the inputs
        for(int i = 0;i<s;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eran . That was silly mistake i was doing there.

Answer (score 0):

You made int array of 501 elements - all initialized by 0 (because it's int type).

Next, you put 5 random integers - on the beginig of array. So you stil have 496 zeros in it - after Arrays.sort(arr) first five elements of your array (which you are printing on standard output) will be zeros. You should look for your elements at the end of array, or initializie your array with `new int[s]`, of course in the moment where s is known.