# merging array then doing sorting and printing them

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I am able to merge array using following code and print it but unable to print the array after I sort it using `Arrays.sort` method.

Where is the problem?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class leetcode4Again {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int a[] = new int[50];
        int b[] = new int[50];
        int merge[] = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int count = 0, size1, size2, size;
        int i = 0, k;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Size : ");
        size1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Size : ");
        size2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            b[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Merging the Arrays...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            merge[i] = a[i];
        }

        size = size1 + size2;

        for (i = 0, k = size1; k < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
            merge[k] = b[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(merge);
        System.out.print("Now the New Array after Merging is :\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(merge[i] + "  ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting to see?  What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: What does _"unable to print the array"_ mean here? Do you get output like `[I@4c75cab9`?  BTW, what you are doing is not called "merging", that term has a specific meaning in data processing.  What you are doing is called "concatenating" two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will get "0 0 0 0 .." answer , because you fill your merge array with zero values at first and then fill some cells of that with a[] and b[] values and still you have some "0" in that , so when you sort that "0" will come first and answer will be wrong. 
so its better you define merge array at first

```
int merge[];
```

but don't initial that value;
then after you get size1 and size2 you can initial that with right size

```
size = size1 + size2;
    merge = new int[size];
    System.out.print("Merging the Arrays...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        merge[i] = a[i];
    } 
    // .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the assigning size to array `merge` , you can find the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450011/why-arrays-sortarr-is-returning-0-values) already answered.

You can fix this issue in following ways :

```
public class leetcode4Again {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int  size1, size2, size;
        int i = 0, k;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Size : ");
        size1 = scan.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[size1];
        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Size : ");
        size2 = scan.nextInt();
        int b[] = new int[size2];
        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            b[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int merge[] = new int[a.length + b.length];
        System.out.print("Merging the Arrays...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            merge[i] = a[i];
        }

        size = size1 + size2;

        for (i = 0, k = size1; k < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
            merge[k] = b[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(merge);

        System.out.print("Now the New Array after Merging is :\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(merge[i] + "  ");
        }

    }
}
```

**Or**

```
//...
int merge[] = new int[size1 + size2];
        System.out.print("Merging the Arrays...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            merge[i] = a[i];
        }
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

What happend is you have an array with a lot of empty spaces, unless you actually filled 50 elements in the first array and 50 at the second array.
Arrays.sort is sorting the merge array, which you defined 100 element places for it, but in reality, if you have'nt filled both arrays, this merge array will be filled with a lot of zeros (defualt in java, if you have'nt changed an array element it is 0), and because sort starts from the bottom to the top, all the 0's will be first in line when u are printing the array. How to solve this? 
just declare merge array with the the exact number of places you need, so you won't have 0's, and this number is size= size1+size2, just like you did in your code. If something isn't clear, ask me. Hope it'll be helpful

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class leetcode4Again {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int a[] = new int[50];
        int b[] = new int[50];

        int count = 0, size1, size2, size;
        int i = 0, k;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Size : ");
        size1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Array 1 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Size : ");
        size2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Array 2 Elements : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            b[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        size = size1 + size2; //change
        int merge[] = new int[size]; //change
        System.out.print("Merging the Arrays...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            merge[i] = a[i];
        }

        for (i = 0, k = size1; k < size && i < size2; i++, k++) {
            merge[k] = b[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(merge);
        System.out.print("Now the New Array after Merging is :\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(merge[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this link, it is properly explaining how to merge two arrays and print them, you need to search such questions on internet first, there are plenty of examples already available
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/arrays_merge.htm
 the problem with your code is after sorting 0s are coming at start of an array of length 100 and you print only first few elements, however, refer to link above to execute such tasks